# Rock Paper Scissors for arbitrary odd number of elements

Tags: math

How do I efficiently create a rock-scissors-paper game for n elements, 
where n is any odd number >=3.

In other words, I want a non-transitive complete ordering of n elements 
such that each element is greater than (n-1)/2 other elements and each 
element is lesser than (n-1)/2 other elements.

Comment: Efficient in what way? Code density? Executable size or speed? Memory use? How big can N be?

Answer (score 7):

Assume your items are numbered 0,1,2,...,n-1.

Item i beats item j iff `i - j (mod n) > (n-1)/2`.

In other words you can rotate the list such that your chosen item is in the middle of the list:

```
i - (n-1) / 2, ..., i-2, i-1, i, i+1, i+2, ..., i + (n-1) / 2
```

Then item i beats all the items below it in the list.

A matrix of i vs j would look like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 - L L W W
1 W - L L W
2 W W - L L
3 L W W - L
4 L L W W -
```

This is not the only possibility, but it is probably the simplest. You can construct any matrix that obeys these rules:

- All values on the diagonal are zero.
- The other values are 1 or -1 (win, lose).
- It is a [skew symmetric matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix).
- It has exactly (n-1)/2 wins and losses in every row and column.

Here is another more complex example:

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 - L W W L
1 W - W L L
2 L L - W W
3 L W L - W
4 W W L L -
```

Or phrased another way:

```
0 beats 2 and 3.
1 beats 0 and 2.
2 beats 3 and 4.
3 beats 1 and 4.
4 beats 0 and 1.
```

In this example it may be possible to relabel the items to give the same logic as in the previous game. I doubt that holds in general though.

Comment: btw, if you are interested, this is a tournament graph: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory) with score sequence s_i = (n-1)/2.

Answer (score 3):

Fantastic, thanks!

As another approach (inspired by yours), k beats k+1 (mod n-1), k+2 (mod n-1), etc... for the next (n-1)/2 elements.

Comment: Hot tip o the day: Hit the "accepted answer"-icon next to his post if it answers your question in a good way, instead of adding an answer to your own question ;-)

Comment: Agreed about Accepted Answers but just to be clear, answers to one's own questions are very much encouraged.  In particular, this seems worthy of being a separate answer.  (Good to make it stand on its own though and reserve dialog with other answerers for the comments.)